# Stored procedure in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I have inherited a MVC4 application using Entity Framework 5 and .NET Framework 4 and this is in C#. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2

Here is my problem.

Inside my database I have a stored procedure. This stored procedure takes in two `varchar` parameters  to run.

I believe, I have the stored procedure in my `.edmx`.

I want this to fire off when two text boxes are populated.

How do I go about having the partial view call the stored procedure and return the data to the appropriate text boxes?

Sorry this is a massive question I am just at a loss at work and any help is appreciated!

If I have forgot anything or any more information is needed please let me know and I will provide what I can.

Thanks in advance for the help,
Dustin

Comment: If you have your SP in your EDMX file , then all you need to do is a function import then use it in your controller to populate the textboxes

Comment: When is the partial view supposed to call this SP? on a button click?

Comment: @meda I am trying to figure out where this function import is located.

Comment: @krilovich When the two text boxes have values in them

Comment: Open the EDMX file and goto model browser property window. There you need to expand the list of stored procs from the database and just double click on the proc you need to import.

Comment: @Nilesh Thank you It is now in my Entity container.

Comment: So the new question is now that it is in my entity container, How do I get my web page to call this and populate the other fields?

Comment: @DustinHarrell you would this in you controller action

Comment: It is as simple as calling some function from the context. I don't have access to VS so cannot give an example. But am sure you will figure it out.

Comment: Ok once again sorry for asking so many question, new grad and all, Inside the Controller would this be something like this?

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FillFS(AFViewModel ViewModel)
{

return PartialView("_AFTab");
}

Comment: You are on right track. Were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Not yet. Im trying to figure out where I can call the Stored Procedure and pass in the variables at the moment

Comment: @DustinHarrell see my answer it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't think  goes in the  `[HttpPost]` controller it should be in the GET one

```
public ActionResult FillFS(AFViewModel ViewModel) 
{ 
            try
            {       
            //Execute the SP
            var TextBoxList = GetListOfTextBox("somevar","somevar2");

            //Code to populate
            //ViewModel.TextBox1 && ViewModel.TextBox2      

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Response.Write(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }

        return PartialView("_AFTab"); 
}
```

Here I just wrapped the function import.

```
    public static List<SPResult> GetListOfTextBox(string varchar1, string, varchar2)
    {
        using (var db = new EDMXEntities())
        {
            //GetTextBoxValue is the name you gave to the function import
            ObjectResult<SPResult> Results = db.GetTextBoxValue(varchar1, varchar2);
            List<SPResult> results = Results.ToList();

            return results;
        }

    }
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This looks like it will work I'm currently trying to get the individual items out of var TextBoxList

Comment: @DustinHarrell ok bro let me know if you need further help

Comment: Alright I have the Controller "Right" How do I make the model call this by just having two text boxes populated?
JavaScript?

Comment: Don't need js, if your view is strongly typed then use html helper textboxfor

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FPrograms.IO1)

Something along these lines?

Comment: Exactly that will populate your textbox

Comment: Actually I got it all figured out now and it runs (most of the way) Now I just have to get values from the form into the method but the major battle is won. Thank yo so much for the patience and the help!
I cant upvote answer or I would. I'm new to SO so if I can upvote you or what not let me know so you get the rep.